# How to make layout components responsive in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-activity, responsive-design

I am designing an activity where I want to put 5 `buttons` and for that I want to design a systematic layout to contain all those button as shown in the image below.[image: Activity]

I am getting success to design such layout by hard coded values. But, its resulting in destructed UI while testing on the screens of different sizes. My question is that what to do if I want to design the app UI for multiple screen resolutions? Is there any way to design by using `wrap_content` and `match_parent`? By searching I got one solution that we can design different layouts for single activity as suitable for the screen size. But is it reliable? 
My xml code is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upbtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftbtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/centerbtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rightbtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/downbtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use linear layout along with weights or you can go with the new Constraint layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this layout, I have added weights as per your needs and relevant height and width for all the views which matches your requirements. Tested in all the devices and looks good. Removed margin top for first layout but you can keep it if you like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/upbtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftbtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/centerbtn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rightbtn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/downbtn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ConstraintLayout` its more suitable for your work. Using `GuideLine` in constriantlayout you can skip the hard coded values and instead divide your space based on percentages of screen area.

Here is the reference for getting started : https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html